# How is heuristic-based virus detection possible?

Tags: malware, malware-detection, halting-problem

The Halting Problem states that it is impossible for one program to predict the output of another, or whether it will terminate.

That got me thinking... how do heuristics based-scanners decide whether a given executable program's instructions are "virus-like", seeing as that would entirely involve predicting what the program is going to do?

Comment: I believe the first step is to see whether any code matches code from known viruses. Sort of like how the first step to guessing passwords is to try the most commonly-used passwords.

Comment: @William: That's the traditional approach of virus scanners, yes, but I thought the whole point of heuristics-based virus scanning was to be able to detect *unknown* viruses, albeit with some false positives and negatives.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not specific enough for [SO]. Maybe on [programmers.se]?

Comment: That's not quite what the halting problem says. Turing proved that a *general* solution for *all possible* programs cannot exist. In theory, the output of *some* code could be predicted. No idea if any malware scanners attempt that.

Comment: There’s a level of analysis you can do on the file based on pattern matching, but the real power of heuristic-based virus detection comes in when the malware actually runs. The AV hooks into suspicious things and blocks them. Sure, you have to run it to completely get around the Halting problem, but it can work rather well.

Comment: @icktoofay That's what makes it a heuristic! To use my analogy, a password-guessing *algorithm* would try every possible combination, in order, based on the algorithm. But a password-guessing *heuristic* employs some guesswork and shortcuts, like a table of known passwords.

Comment: Detection is not 100%.... there are some false positive also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually viruses use some kind of "pattern" in their code, like opening some special registry keys or execution of rare used system functions, or self-code modifications, so analyzer can "see" these actions and mark such program as potentially virus, of course it has some percentage of false alarm

Comment: Furthermore, the algorithm can "learn", just as the human immune system can learn how to recognize pathogens.